# Angular2 app optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am writing app on Angular2 and have some problems. 
Context: i have 3 arrays and i should filter two array of the third.
Example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] //get async 1 times
b = [1,2,5] //get async 1 times
c = [{a:1,b:2},{a:2,b:5}] //get async many times
```

And i should get `a = [3,4,5] b = [1]`.

My solution in angular2:

I created `Map<a>` and `Map<b>` and filter arrays in template with them.

```
<div *ngIf="!excludeCompetitors.has(competitor.id)" (click)="selectCompetitor(competitor)">{{competitor.shortName}} - {{competitor.longName}}</div>
```

But i think its not effective because Angular ChangeDetection. Maybe i should calculate arrays and work with computed arrays?

Comment: You should generally avoid function calls in evaluated expressions because they will run on every CD cycle.

Comment: @j2L4e yeah, i know, but it simple option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter function like below:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [1,2,5];
var c = [{a:1,b:2},{a:2,b:5}];
var fa = filter(a, c[0]);
var fb = filter(b, c[1]);
console.log("fa: ", fa);
console.log("fb: ", fb);
// -------------- //
filter(arr, filt): number[] {
    return arr.filter(item => {
        var keys = Object.keys(filt);
        return !keys.some(key => filt[key] === item);
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want a and b to be updated whenever c change, you can use Angular pipe:

```
// Your pipe:

@Pipe({ name: 'arrayFilter' })
export class ArrayFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(arr: number[], filt: any) {
        console.log("filter called");
        return arr.filter(item => {
            var keys = Object.keys(filt);
            return !keys.some(key => filt[key] === item);
        });
    }
}

// Add the pipe in declarations of your module:

@NgModule({
    // ...
    declarations: [ ArrayFilter ],
    // ...
})

// In your template:

<div *ngFor="let n of a | arrayFilter: c[0]"> {{ n }}</div>
<div *ngFor="let n of b | arrayFilter: c[1]"> {{ n }}</div>

// In your component:

a = [1,2,3,4,5];
b = [1,2,5];
c = [{a:1, b:2},{a:2, b:5}];
```

Comment: Yeah, i thought about that, but a and b i get async 1 times c array get many times. And even manipulation with `c` array i should will update a and b array